# What's wrong with this DIV background image assignment?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var bgimages ='myImage.png'

var pathToImg=new Array(), i=0
pathToImg[0]=new Image()
pathToImg[0].src=bgimages

document.body.background=pathToImg[i].src
```

// the above works
however, when I attempted to change the "body" element to a "DIV" with id of "slide" it fails, fyi, this div exists

```
document.getElementById('slide').style.background-image = pathToImg[i].src
```

Or what's the correct syntax for setting a DIV background imagine dynamically?

Thanks.

- addition, full code

```js
// image slideshow script 2
var bgimages=new Array()
bgimages[0]="paper-n.jpg"
bgimages[1]="kn-n.png"
// bgimages[2]="img3.jpg"

//preload images
var pathToImg=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgimages.length;i++){
  pathToImg[i]=new Image()
  pathToImg[i].src=bgimages[i]
}

var inc=-1

function bgSlide(){
  if (inc < bgimages.length-1)
    inc++
  else
    inc=0
  // document.body.background=pathToImg[inc].src
  document.getElementById('slide').style['background-image'] = pathToImg[inc].src
  // "url('" + pathToImg[i].src + "')";
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
  window.onload=new Function('setInterval("bgSlide()",3000)')
```

```css
// slideshow
body {
  /*Remove below line to make bgimage NOT fixed*/
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*Use center center in place of 300 200 to center bg image*/
  background-position: 300 200;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, please share more code with us. It might be that you run your javascript code to early (before div) or div with id 'slide' does not exist.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks.  I attempted to add DIV in addition to BODY for the style to no avail.

Comment: @Dario has correct answer, I have modified your code and put it to his answer as a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `style` using `[]` instead of a `.`, like this :

```
document.getElementById('slide').style['background-image'] = pathToImg[i].src;
```

Comment: Style properties are camelcase.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use backgroundImage instead of background-image.

```
document.getElementById('slide').style.backgroundImage = pathToImg[i].src
```

Like in the example here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundimage2

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp) you should write something like:

```
document.getElementById("slide").style["background-image"] = "url('" + pathToImg[i].src + "')";
```

**EDIT**
Modified working code

```js
// image slideshow script 2
var bgimages=new Array()
bgimages[0]="http://dummyimage.com/200x123/0f0/00f"
bgimages[1]="http://dummyimage.com/200x123/f00/00f"
// bgimages[2]="img3.jpg"

//preload images
var pathToImg=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgimages.length;i++){
  pathToImg[i]=new Image()
  pathToImg[i].src=bgimages[i]
}

var inc=-1

function bgSlide(){
  
  if (inc < bgimages.length-1)
    inc++
  else
    inc=0

  // BOTH of following works
  //document.getElementById('slide').style.backgroundImage = "url("+pathToImg[inc].src+")";
  document.getElementById('slide').style['background-image'] = "url('"+pathToImg[inc].src+"')";
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
  window.onload=new Function('setInterval("bgSlide()",3000)')
```

```css
// slideshow
body {
  /*Remove below line to make bgimage NOT fixed*/
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*Use center center in place of 300 200 to center bg image*/
  background-position: 300 200;
}

#slide {
  width : 200px;
  height : 123px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide">This is my div</div>
```

Comment: Hi all, I tried each of the solutions recommended, however, I'm getting errors, same error actually, err msg: Cannot read property 'style' of null  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have element with id "slide" in your html? The code I posted works, check this link: http://jsbin.com/mekaxa/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `style`:

```
document.body.style.background=pathToImg[i].src
              ^^^^^
```

`background` is a CSS-ism, not something that's part of the `<body>` tag itself.

Comment: the following code works, so, let's leave it alone, instead, let's focus on the one that has a prob, tks.  document.body.background=pathToImg[i].src